# Loss of data from Bluetooth to UART

Tags: android, bluetooth, embedded, microcontroller, pic

I am using [PIC18F87J11](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/39778e.pdf) and [RN42 Bluetooth module](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/rn-42-ds-v2.32r.pdf) with 38400  baud rate. I made an android app that connects to the Bluetooth module and sends some data from my phone to the Micrcontroller. Everything is good but I noticed sometimes I lose some data. The PIC18 is expecting about 100 characters, if the app sends those 100 characters there are no issues, but sometimes it sends about 98 characters. Then the PIC18 keeps waiting for 2 more characters, but the next time the app sends something its 100 characters long.

This is causing the app to out of sync with the Microcontroller, since the first byte represents a command. I have about 20 ms delay between each characters I send but that didn't solve the problem. This doesn't happen all the time but when it happens it mess ups everything. I tried increasing the time delay which seems to be helpful but I don't want it to be too slow.

What is causing some of the data to be lost and how do I fix it?

**UART code and Interrupt**

```
#define CLOCK_FREQ 8000000 
#define BAUD_RATE 38400
#define SPBRG_VAL   ( ((CLOCK_FREQ/BAUD_RATE)/16) - 1)

void ConsoleInit(void)
{
 TRISCbits.TRISC7 = 1;
 TRISCbits.TRISC6 = 0;
 TXSTA = 0x24;
 RCSTA = 0x90; // 0b10010000;
 SPBRG = SPBRG_VAL;
}

BYTE ConsoleGet(void)
{
   if(RCSTAbits.OERR)
        {
        RCSTAbits.CREN = 0;   // Disable UART receiver
        RCSTAbits.CREN = 1;   // Enable UART receiver
        }

        return RCREG;
}


void timerInit (void)
{
// Time Period Achieved : 0.001s
T0CONbits.T08BIT = 0;
T0CONbits.T0CS = 0;
T0CONbits.PSA = 1;
TMR0H = 0xF8;
TMR0L = 0x30;
T0CONbits.TMR0ON = 1;
}
```

**Interrupt Routine**

```
if (TMR_IF) {
TMR0H = 0xF8;
TMR0L = 0x30;
  if (PIR1bits.RCIF )
           {
                ProcessMenu(); // In this function I call ConsoleGet() and have switch statment 
           }

        if (INTCONbits.TMR0IE) {
            /* there was a timer overflow */
            PIR1bits.RCIF = 0;

        }

    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: I added 30 ms time delay between each characters and no issues yet, however its takes longer to send 100 characters. I need to send more about 1000 messages and each message is 100 characters long. This process would take more than 30 minutes which very long. How do I reduce the time delay without losing data? Do I need to increase the baud rate or something?

Comment: I increased the baud rate to 500k to see if it would be better, it had no effect, I still lose data without the 30 ms time delay. I'm confused!

Comment: Please consider adding the UART init code, the interrupt routine ou your receive from uart routine? Without a code, there's so many places where it could go wrong.

Answer (score 2):

When the receiving program is losing bytes received through a UART, it typically means that the receiving program is not servicing the UART's receive interrupt fast enough.  The UART can only hold a limited number of received bytes, maybe only one.  So your program has to read the received byte out of the UART before the UART receives the next byte.  If you don't read the character from the UART before the next byte arrives then the UART will discard a byte and your program will lose it.

If you're using an ISR to handle the UART's receive interrupt then I can think of two likely reasons that your program may not service the interrupt fast enough.  One reason is that the program may spend too much time servicing a higher priority interrupt.  Then the lower priority UART receive interrupt may get postponed for too long and the UART will drop bytes.  Do you have a higher priority ISRs that executes for many milliseconds?

The second reason is that your program may be spending too much time in the receive interrupt itself.  Your ISR calls ProcessMenu() which seems suspicious.  If ProcessMenu() does a lot of processing and takes longer than the inter-character delay of the serial interface then your program won't be able to service the receive interrupt fast enough and the UART will drop bytes.  What is the maximum execution time of ProcessMenu()?

These reasons are two examples of why there is a general rule of thumb to keep ISRs short.

If ProcessMenu() is indeed taking too long then the fix is, don't call ProcessMenu() from within the ISR.  The ISR should simply read the byte from the UART and copy it to a circular receive buffer in RAM.  This way the ISR completes very quickly and is ready again before the UART receives another byte.  Then, outside of the ISR, the main programming loop should poll the receive buffer and call ProcessMenu() when there are bytes available.

Comment: Your answer makes sense, +1. Before I wasn't using UART interrupt, I was just scanning for `PIR1bits.RC1IF` on the while loop, now I do use UART interrupt but indeed `ProcessMenu()` is taking too long to finish. I will try your suggestions and see where that leads me.

Answer (score 1):

The PIC18F87J11 has 2 different UART modules, UART1 and UART2. You must specify which one you are using when writing to registers. You neither do use BAUDCON to specify whether the baudrate value is 8 or 16bits,

```
TXSTA1 = 0b00100100; // TXEN, BRGH
RCSTA1 = 0b10010000; // SPEN, CREN (ASYNC assume)
BAUDCON1 = 0b00000000; //8 bit baudrate at 38400.
SPBRGL = .12;         //ecimal value for 38400 BS, 0.16% error
```

That's for the UART1 initialisation. Inputs / outputs are driven by the uart module directly as said in the datasheet *The EUSARTx control will automatically
reconfigure the pin from input to output as
needed.*

Then, in your interrupt routine, you're messing up some thing, assuming you've set the necessary bits :

`PIE.RC1IE = 1; //Enable receive interrupt 
IPEN = 0;       //All masked interrupt enabled
GIE = 1;        // 
PEIE = 1;       //Enable peripheral interrupts (RC1IE)`

Then, **inside the brackets of your interrupt routine**

```
   INTCON.GIE = 0;   //Disable all interrupts
   //Series of IF to gather interrupt source
   if (PIR1.RC1IF)    //Receive serial flag up?
    {
      if (ucTrackBuffer >= BufferSize){ucTrackBuffer= 0;}
      //if ucTrackBuffer >= BufferSize, reset 0.
      ucTabRx232[ucIndiceTampon] = RCREG1;//Receive uart to buffer
      ucTrackBuffer++;                    //increm buffer tracking
    }
   INTCON.GIE = 1;               //Re-start interrupts
   PIR1.RCIF = 0;                //Lower flag to permit a second interrupt
```

All this code may help you. Watch out for the brackets in your ISR, plus never call a function in an ISR as you may skip precious instruction cycles (skip a character!).

Interrupt service

```
if (PIR1.RC1IF)
 {
   //Code for serial reception
 }
if (TMR1_IF)
 { 
   //Code for timer1 overflow
 }
```

Hope that helps, let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: It's strange that all this didn't help resolve the problem or even made it better. The only way the UART doesn't break is when I add 30 ms time delay between each characters being sent on the Android app. At this point, I don't know if its the Micro or the APP causing this problem, +1 though for your support.

Comment: Have you removed the receive interrupt routine from the timer interrupt routine and seperated them as I said?

If you did not, maybe the RX interrupt only catches up when the timer overflows.

Comment: I tried it but I didn't see any improvements, still buggy.

Comment: At least get sure with a scope, logic analyzer or even PC uart that the baudrate is good, try sending from the PIC any characters to the PC (that way we'll be sure that UART is properly initialized)

Comment: I know the baudrate is good since I can write and get characters from UART. The only problem I have is the fact that sometimes the characters are not being received by the PIC when I send them from my android app.